# Connecting to MariaDB + Bitnami's Multi-tier

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, mariadb

I'm still new to AWS and this is my first attempt at working with MariaDB; I'm used to dealing with hosting providers that already have something like cPanel installed so please be nice. :)

I'm using [Bitnami's WordPress Multi-Tier with Amazon RDS for MariaDB](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01MXM8W5Q)

Bitnami's documentation is usually quite good, but in this particular case I'm not finding anything. I've reached out to their support and the only reply I've received until now was something akin to: *"use a WordPress plugin to make database exports"* which is obviously isn't going to cut the mustard when it comes to importing.

What I want to accomplish:

1. Connect to my database
2. Export my database
3. Import (overwrite) a database

Essentially, I want to deploy my local WordPress to AWS...files are all good, but I'm lost when it comes to databases.

*(NOTE: I want to get out of the habit of relying on phpMyAdmin and, ideally, don't want to have to go through installing it, etc)*

I started here: [Connecting to a DB Instance Running the MariaDB Database Engine][2]

After SSH'ing in I've tried:

Command: `mysql`

Outputs: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

---

Command: `mysql -h MY-DB-INSTANCE.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u bitnami`

Outputs: `Access denied for user 'bitnami'@'10.0.4.110' (using password: NO)`

EDIT: I've split this thread into a separate one for other issues that I ran into.

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks and noted. I've opened a new thread for the other issues that I was coming across as I was trying to work through things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your MySQL user `bitnami` actually has a password, so you may try this:

```
mysql -h MY-DB-INSTNACE.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u bitnami -p
                                                                       ^^^ add this
```

Your shell should prompt you for the password.

Beyond this, you need to make sure that you have opened your RDS instance to the IP from which you are trying to connect.  You could open it to all IPs, but it is better practice to just open it to your dev machine, as well as the production machines which would be hitting the database.  If you don't do this step, you also would not be able to connect.

**Edit:** If your user `bitnami` does not yet exist, then you may have to login as root and configure.  Or perhaps you would have to reset the password if forgotten.  You should always write down the admin credentials, as a last resort means of accessing your RDS instance.

Comment: Hey Tim!

Thanks for the answer. That `-p` bit was helpful. I'm now prompted for a password, but when I enter it I get:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bitnami'@'10.0.4.110' (using password: YES)`

RE: "Opening up RDS Instance" - Could you point me to the right direction on how to do that? I'm still learning this stuff and am not even sure what to Google in order to find documentation :)

Massive thanks!

Comment: I've never done user management on MySQL on RDS before.  I always have used the admin account created when I first configured it on AWS.  Obviously, either the user does not exist, or you have the wrong password.

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for another quick reply! I tried the user as `root` (which I'm guessing is a security issue and a bridge that I'll need to cross eventually) and that let me connect. From here I'll try to find some MariaDB/MysQL documentation on managing things via shell but if you've any tips that would be ver much appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: @RyanDorn Go ahead and ask another question if you still have issues.  The problem with long sprawling questions on SO is that they aren't very useful to other people, because they are not focused enough.